# How to change Python shell editor to vim

Tags: vim, python

I always have this question about how to change the python shell editor.

simple example:

```
$python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import datetime
>>> help(datetime)
```

the help() command opens unkonwn editor as default. Can I change it to make it open the help docs in vim instead?

Answer (score 3):

`help()` should open a pager, not an editor. Sounds like your environment variables are a bit mixed up. The pager is controlled by `$PAGER`, and if blank it will use `more`. You should probably unset it.

The default editor, which (eg) IPython uses for its `%edit` command, can be set via the `$EDITOR` variable.

Comment: is there anyway to change the editor for default python terminal?